# macOS Catalina 10.15.4 - Google Maps not working

Tags: android, macos, 64-bit, android-virtual-device, genymotion

I'm working on Android project that heavily relies on Google Maps. 
My work machine is MacBook Pro and I use Genymotion Emulator. 
The problem started when I updated my Mac to macOS Catalina 10.15.4.
Since the system supports only x64 applications and there's some Apple location permission issues, nor Genymotion or AV can run my app. Even in Chrome when I try to locate my computer in google maps it doesn't work!

1. Is there a way to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: macOS Catalina supports only 64bit apps, but Genymotion Desktop is a 64bit app so it works on Catalina, and once you install opengapps in it you can run Google Maps. I just did it to verify.

Comment: I tried it too. GApps are installed. Even downloaded apps fro Google Play who's using google maps are not working. Google Chrome cannot verify my address because system doesn't give him a permissions. It finds on Safari tho. I guess it has something to do with permissions

Comment: What kind of device have you created?

Comment: It was an Android 6.0 (so API 21). But I see you fixed this with an API 23 device. Going to try with an API 19 to see if I reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
For some reason on new macOS I cannot properly run Genymotion devices wit API 19. I created new device w API 21 and it works now.